# Finding a sum to infinity with a factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The sequence is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n-1}{n!}$$

I could show that it converges using the Ratio test, but evaluating it seems to be hard. I'm trying to avoid power series and Taylor series and such. Is it possible to solve this some other, simpler way?

I tried writing out the first few terms, but since it's non-geometric, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: "evaluating it seems to be hard": have you even tried ? This ratio test is quite easy.

Comment: Finding the first few partial sums might help: $\frac{0}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{24}+\frac{4}{120}+\cdots$ $=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{6}+\frac{3}{24}+\frac{4}{120}+\cdots$ $=\frac{5}{6}+\frac{3}{24}+\frac{4}{120}+\cdots$ $=\frac{23}{24}+\frac{4}{120}+\cdots$ $=\frac{119}{120}+\cdots$

Comment: @Henry Thank you. I can't see how the partial sums, expressed in that form, can possibly help. Is there some hidden easy-to-follow pattern I'm missing in those expressions?

Comment: @Joanpemo: there is a pattern in the sequence $\dfrac{0}{1}, \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{5}{6}, \dfrac{23}{24}, \dfrac{119}{120}, \ldots$. Can you spot what it might converge to? And what the precise pattern is?  Then use induction for proof.

Comment: @Henry Thank you. I can see, with some effort, that if those are really the partial sums, then the limit is one, and this is correct, yet I can't see how could this pattern be reached in general (and proved in general) without first stumbling in one of the already given answers.

Comment: @Henry thank you! This is a good method which avoids having to use Euler's constant, which was what I was hoping to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Note that

$$\frac{n - 1}{n!} = \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} - \frac{1}{n!}$$

A large amount of cancellations will occur between successive terms in the summation.

Comment: Probably the most elegant using elementary observations like telescoping series.

Answer (score 3):

Your sum is only

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n-1}{n!}=\sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^\infty\overbrace{\frac1{n!}}^{=\frac n{n!}=\frac1{(n-1)!}}-\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^\infty\frac1{n!}=e^1-(e^1-1)=1$$

Comment: Avoids cleverness.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you. Yes, perhaps...but makes, in my opinion, things pretty simple using a very well known infinite series.

Comment: Nice and straightforward. +1

Comment: Nice answer! Sorry I couldn't accept it as the correct answer but if I could choose two I'd have chosen this.

Comment: @SkeletonBow Thank you. Don't worry about the accepting: choose whatever you consider the best/more helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{\mathbb e^x}{x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$ And use derivativetion we get that: $$\frac{x\mathbb e^x-\mathbb e^x}{x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n-1)x^{n-2}}{n!}$$ Or: $$\frac{x\mathbb e^x-\mathbb e^x}{x^2}+\frac1{x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n-1)x^{n-2}}{n!}$$ Finally: $$1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!}$$.